# Help with Input and Output relationships?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Here's the question: Give three examples of input-output relationships in **real life** that cannot have negative values in the practical range? Explain why their range cannot have negative values?

It's a confusing question because how can a relationship have both and input and output?

Could time be a input-output relationship?

Comment: "Input-output relationship" is not a standard mathematical term, so if your teacher is using that, zie should have told you what it was supposed to mean. In mathematics, we speak of things like *functions* (also called *mappings*), which I suspect are what you're talking about. We also speak of *relations*, which are a more abstract/general concept.

Comment: Maybe that's why I'm so confused, Nothing about the question really makes sense to me, How can something have a an "imput-output" relationship? that has a practical range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an example of an input-output relationship, just think about a function.

For instance, suppose $f$ is a function that tracks revenue at a lemonade stand. It takes "number of cups sold" as an input and gives "dollars made" as an output. It might look like this:

$f(x)=.25x$

Assuming that each cup of lemonade costs .25 cents. So if I sell $5$ cups, then I make:

$f(5)=.25(5)=1.25$ dollars. If I sell 20 cups, I make:

$f(10)=.25(10)=2.50$ dollars. In this case, we call $10$ the input and $2.50$ the output. Does that make sense?

Also note: the domain of $f$ in this example is $[0,\infty).$ That is, the input value must be positive, since we can't sell a negative number of cups. The range is also positive, since $.25*(a\,non-negative\,number)$ is always non-negative.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks so much, your able to make break it down so I can understand  it.